# NIntegrate 2 variables function over one variable only

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a very complex integral that has to be evaluated numerically. The integrand (p) is a function of two variables (z, Lx), and the integral is on Lx.

I get an error with the output, and from what I get the problem here is that the I need to integrate on the other variable too (that is exactly what I'd like to avoid).

Is there any way to work around this problem?
The code works, so if you try to run it you will see what I'd like to obtain, the only problem is that the results are slightly wrong compared to literature (a factor 3 or 5, depending on the parameters adopted).

Here is my code, thanks in advance.

```
constants = {A -> 1.21/10^6, p1 -> 4.62, p2 -> -1.15, zc0 -> 2.49, 
  alpha -> 0.2, La -> 10^45.74, L0 -> 10^44.25, g1 -> 1.01, 
  g2 -> 2.38, \[CapitalOmega]m -> 0.3, \[CapitalOmega]l -> 
   0.7, \[CapitalOmega]r -> 0, h -> 0.7, c -> 300000, H0 -> 70, 
  Fov -> 4.476176190127657*^-7, Mpc2cm -> 3.08567758*10^24}

phizero[Lx_] := A/((Lx/L0)^g1 + (Lx/L0)^g2);
p0[L1_, L2_] := NIntegrate[ Lx*phizero[Lx] /. constants, {Lx, L1, L2}];
zc[Lx_] := 
  Piecewise[{{zc0, Lx >= La}, {zc0*(Lx/La)^alpha, Lx < La}}];
e[z_, Lx_] := 
  Piecewise[{{(1 + z)^p1, 
     z <= zc[Lx]}, {(1 + zc[Lx])^p1*((1 + z)/(1 + zc[Lx]))^p2, 
     z > zc[Lx]}}];
phi[z_, Lx_] := phizero[Lx]*e[z, Lx];
 p[z_, L1_, L2_] := 
  NIntegrate[Lx^-1 phi[z, Lx] /. constants, {Lx, L1, L2}];
(*p[3,10^44.5,10^45.5]*)
Manipulate[
 LogPlot[p[z, 10^L1, 10^L2], {z, 0.1, 7}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  AxesLabel -> {"z", \[Phi]  [\!\(TraditionalForm\`
\*FractionBox[\(1\), 
SuperscriptBox[\(Mpc\), \(3\)]]\)]} ], {L1, 42, 47}, {L2, 43, 47}]
```

Comment: see here,  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8899/how-do-i-prevent-nintegrateinumr-errors-within-other-functions you need to define p and p0 so that they evaluate only for numeric arguments.